# Highlighting strings between < and > in lstlistings

Tags: lstlisting

The listings package provides the option moredelim, allowing for custom styles for words enclosed by given delimiters. I would like to give <...> an custom colors, however, doesn't seem to work well. MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,128,0}
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{238,239,240}
\definecolor{header}{RGB}{163,21,21}
\definecolor{hinclude}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
     language=C++,
     extendedchars=true, 
     breaklines=true,
     breakatwhitespace=true,
     basicstyle=\ttfamily,
     keywordstyle=\color{darkblue},
     keywordstyle=[2]\color{blue},
     keywordstyle=[3]\color{darkblue},
     keywordstyle=[4]\color{darkgreen},
     alsoletter = {!},
     tabsize=2,
     moredelim = [s][\color{header}]{\#}{>},
     literate=
            *{\#include}{{\textcolor{hinclude}{\#include}}}{8}
            {>}{{\textcolor{header}{>}}}{1},
     moredelim = [s][\color{header}]{<}{>},
     keywords=[2]{cout,cin},
 }

\newtcblisting{code}{
      arc=0mm,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=3mm,
      right=0mm,
      width=\textwidth,
      boxrule=1pt,
      colback=lightgray,
      listing only,
      listing options={style=mystyle},
      breakable
}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int bfs(int startNode, int endNode)
{
  memset(parentsList, -1, sizeof(parentsList));
  memset(currentPathCapacity, 0, sizeof(currentPathCapacity));

  queue<int> q;

  while (!q.empty())
  {
    int currentNode = q.front();
    q.pop();

    for (int i = 0; i < graph[currentNode].size(); i++)
    {
      int to = graph[currentNode][i];
      if (parentsList[to] == -1)
      {
        if (capacities[currentNode][to] - flowPassed[currentNode][to] > 0)
        {
        }

  cout << "enter the number of nodes and edges\n";
  cin >> nodesCount >> edgesCount;

  for (int edge = 0; edge < edgesCount; edge++)
  {
    cout << "enter the start and end vertex alongwith capacity\n";
    int from, to, capacity;
    cin >> from >> to >> capacity;

  }
}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to include the c program in the header file custom color between < and >, but the program code is smaller than and greater than the symbol and input >>, the output symbol << the middle of the code is also incorrectly colored.

I want to achieve this effect：

[image]

Comment: Can't you make your example shorter?

Comment: OK,Program code has been streamlined.

Comment: The effect map I hope to achieve is added.